# How to make this query simple and short. (my_sql) and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, phpmyadmin

I provide two php which contain two type of query, can someone help me to make this query shorter than this. Thanks in advance

```
<?php $sel = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( form ) AS ML FROM webcm WHERE department ='PDN-ML' AND DATE = CURDATE()");
$get_sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel); 
$PDNML1 = $get_sel['ML'];

$sel1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( form ) AS HM FROM webcm WHERE department ='PDN-HM' AND DATE = CURDATE()");
$get_sel1 = mysql_fetch_array($sel1); 
$PDNHM1 = $get_sel1['HM'];

$sel2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( form ) AS AI FROM webcm WHERE department ='AI' AND DATE = CURDATE()");
$get_sel2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel2); 
$AI1 = $get_sel2['AI'];

$sel3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( form ) AS SMT FROM webcm WHERE department ='SMT' AND DATE = CURDATE()");
$get_sel3 = mysql_fetch_array($sel3); 
$SMT1 = $get_sel3['SMT'];?>
```

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(`ML`) AS `ML`,
       SUM(`HM`) AS `HM`,
       SUM(`AI`) AS `AI`,
       SUM(`SMT`) AS `SMT`
FROM (
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN department='PDN-ML' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ML`,
       SUM( CASE WHEN department='PDN-HM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `HM`,
       SUM( CASE WHEN department='AI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `AI`,
       SUM( CASE WHEN department='SMT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `SMT`
FROM webcm 
WHERE DEPARTMENT IN ('PDN-ML','PDN-HM', 'AI', 'SMT') 
AND DATE = CURDATE()
) AS T
```

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e8fcf/1

Comment: but how to get the value of count for each of it.. like my code above I called ($AI1 = $get_sel2['AI']) to get the value of count for AI..

Comment: You can add where condition And Check where WHERE department ='SMT'

Comment: Then what is the difference between this and the previous query

Comment: Check Now I Edited MY ANSWER @NazirahAnwar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do is :

```
SELECT COUNT( form ) AS ML, department  
FROM webcm WHERE DATE = CURDATE() 
AND DEPARTMENT IN ('PDN-ML','PDN-HM', 'AI', 'SMT') 
group by department
```

you can access all , `$get_sel2['ML']` will give you count and `$get_sel2['department']` will give you department name or code.

Then you will have one query result with count and corresponding department.

Comment: then how to get this value ($AI1 = $get_sel2['AI'])

Comment: you can access all , maybe $get_sel2[indec]['ML']

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php $sel = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as ML,department from webcm where DATE = CURDATE() GROUP BY department  ");
$get_sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel); 
$PDNML1 = $get_sel['ML'];
```

OR

```
<?php $sel = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as ML,department from webcm where DATE = CURDATE() and DEPARTMENT IN ('PDN-ML','PDN-HM', 'AI', 'SMT') GROUP BY department  ");
$get_sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel); 
$PDNML1 = $get_sel['ML'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT department,
   case when department='PDN-ML' then COUNT( form ) else 0 end AS ML , 
   case when department='PDN-HM' then COUNT( form ) else 0 end AS HM,
   case when department='AI' then COUNT( form ) else 0 end AS AI,
   case when department='SMT' then COUNT( form ) else 0 end AS SMT,
FROM webcm 
WHERE DEPARTMENT IN ('PDN-ML','PDN-HM', 'AI', 'SMT') 
AND DATE = CURDATE()
GROUP BY department
```